# IntelliJ HTTP Client - using a variable set from one POST request in a following JSON body of another POST request

Tags: http, intellij-idea, client

In HTTP client Editor on IntelliJ, I am trying to do this:

```
POST http://{{host}}/path-to-my-first-resource

Content-Type: application/json

{"field1":"false",
 "field2":"test",
 "field3":"test",
}
```

I got the result of the above POST with this:

```
> {%
client.global.set("my-first-returned-var", response.body.json.var1);
client.global.set("my-second-returned-var", response.body.json.var2);
client.global.set("my-third-returned-var", response.body.json.var3); 
%}
```

The variables have been returned with success. Thus, I am trying to use those variables in a subsequent POST, like that:

```
POST http://{{host}}/path-to-my-second-resource

Content-Type: application/json

{"anotherfield1":"{{my-first-returned-var}}",
 "justanother":"{{my-second-returned-var}}"
}
```

I tried to send the variables in the body with quotes and without quotes, but IntelliJ did not translate the variables inside double curlies. I can use the variables on HTPP Header, like:

```
GET https://my-request
Authorization: Bearer {{my-first-returned-var}}
```

But I could not use these variables in a JSON body.

The API that I'm trying to use is a Spring Boot REST Controller that use Jackson lib to deserialize the body from a request into a Java Object. The error message that Spring Boot return is something like that:

JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

Comment: Is there any chance that you are trying to use "Run all requests in file" link?
There is a bug about it:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-49638

Comment: @user10550971 I have been tested with Run with 'desenv' environment

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this several months ago, but have you tried this:

```js
client.global.set("my-first-returned-var", JSON.stringify(response.body.json.var1));
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question. But I feel it should have landed in the comments rather than as an answer.

Comment: This definitely solved the question for anyone struggling with sending a JSON body request, that should use some variable set in a previous request (which lead me to this question). Without the stringify IntelliJ sends for example `{"key": myVariable}` (which is syntactically wrong JSON) instead of `{"key": "myVariable"}`. So more a bug in IntelliJ, but helpful workaround for this (similiar) type of requests.